# How to send a string array as parameter to Java from xslt?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am calling a java function from xslt which has a string array as a parameter. I tried to convert the string to array using :

```
<xsl:variable name="strArr">
<item>abc@tdm.com</item>
<item>xyz@tdm.com</item>
</xsl:variable>
```

I get this error:

> could not find method com.techm.ump.applicationServices.Email.postMail([ExpressionContext,] #RTREEFRAG, #RTREEFRAG, #STRING, #STRING)"

When I try to convert using :

```
document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='FMail']/*
```

I get this error:

> could not find method com.techm.ump.applicationServices.Email.postMail([ExpressionContext,] #NODESET, #NODESET, #STRING, #STRING)"

Please let me know if there is a way to convert string into a string array in xslt.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 knows the data types string, number, boolean, node-set and result tree fragment. There are no arrays in XSLT. And how the XSLT data types are mapped to Java data types depends mostly on the implementation of a particular XSLT processor. So you need to find out which XSLT processor you use and check the documentation on the types and type mappings for extension functions, then you should know which types you can use in Java as the parameter types of your extension functions and how XSLT types like node-set are mapped.

Comment: Thanks for the info Martin. I am using xsl 2.0. I have changed my java class which would accept string with a comma delimiter and convert into string array.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor? The appearance of #RTREEFRAG which probably means "result tree fragment" suggests that it is an XSLT 1.0 processor. But even XSLT 2.0 does not know any arrays of strings, it has sequences of nodes and/or primitive values as its data types. And of course with XSLT 2.0 it also depends on the XSLT processor's API how XSLT data types are mapped to Java classes and types.

Comment: You are right Martin. I was using 1.0 processor. It would be of great help if you can suggest sites that could help me learn basics of XSLT since I am new to XSLT.